# How would I sort an arraylist of strings that's formatted as a height in java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<String> heights = new ArrayList<String>();

    Comparator<String> setTableNumber = new Comparator<String>(){
          @Override
          public int compare(String o1, String o2){{       
                 return (o1).compareTo(o2);}}};

    Collections.sort(players, setTableNumber);
```

Suppose heights consists Strings that are like this ["5'11"", "6'11"","4'2""]

And I want it to sort from highest to lowest like ["6'11"","5'11"","4'2""]

I'm thinking about using .split('), converting the strings to integers and then multiplying the feet by 12 and then adding that to the second string (after I trim off the ") and comparing two values as inches. But is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *But is there a better way to do it?* - what is the definition of **better** ?

Comment: I suspect that you're going to have to convert the `String` to something more useful (and comparable)

Comment: @ScaryWombat better as in less lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd convert the `String` values to `int` (inches) up-front, this gives you the opportunity to deal with possible errors during conversation.

```
ArrayList<String> heights = new ArrayList<String>();
heights.add("5'11");
heights.add("6'11");
heights.add("5'2");
heights.add("4'2");

Comparator<String> setTableNumber = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer lhs = convertToInches(o1);
        Integer rhs = convertToInches(o2);
        if (lhs == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (rhs == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }

    protected Integer convertToInches(String value) {
        String parts[] = value.split("'");
        if (parts.length != 2) {
            return null;
        }
        return (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 12) + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    }
};

Collections.sort(heights, setTableNumber);
System.out.println(heights);
```

which prints

```
[4'2, 5'2, 5'11, 6'11]
```

This workflow will place "bad" values to the end of the list, for example...

```
ArrayList<String> heights = new ArrayList<String>();
heights.add("Worse");
heights.add("5'11");
heights.add("6'11");
heights.add("5'2");
heights.add("Bad");
heights.add("4'2");
```

will generate

```
[4'2, 5'2, 5'11, 6'11, Worse, Bad]
```

But personally, I'd deal with this before trying to sort the list (by converting the values to `int`).  You can then do some additional formatting to the `int` values when you want to print it

Comment: So 5'2 is shorter than 5'11? No wonder we don't use feet anymore; Do you mean it should be something like 5'02 or 5'20?

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this, 5'11 = 15575.28cm and 5'2 = 1584.96cm, so it "should" work :/

Comment: Ok, now converted to inches, can print `[4'2, 5'11, 5'2, 6'11, Worse, Bad]`

Comment: `return Integer.parseInt(value.split("'")[0]) * 12 +  Integer.parseInt(value.split("'")[1]);`  **output** `[4'2, 5'2, 5'11, 6'11]
`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, "finally" got there - this is why the world works in metrics :P

Comment: You just have to old like me to understand ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to do a lot of things each time you compare.

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> heights = List.of("5'11\"", "6'11\"","4'2\"");

    List<String> sorted = heights.stream()
        .map(s -> new Object() {
            String feetInch = s;
            int inch;
            {
                String[] f = feetInch.replaceFirst("\"", "").split("'");
                inch = Integer.parseInt(f[0]) * 12 + Integer.parseInt(f[1]);
            }
        })
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.inch)))
        .map(obj -> obj.feetInch)
        .toList();

    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```

output:

```
[6'11", 5'11", 4'2"]
```